# How to convert jscarousel to work with semantic html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to recreate this image slider:

http://www.egrappler.com/contents/jsCarousel/demo/jsCarousel.htm

Except using more meaningful html. This page just uses a bunch of random divs, with more divs encapsulating the entire thing:

```
<div id="jsCarousel">
  <div>Image</div>
  <div>Image</div>
  <div>Image</div>
</div>
```

I want my html to look more like:

```
<ul id="jsCarousel">
  <li>Image</li>
  <li>Image</li>
  <li>Image</li>
</ul>
```

But I can't tell which div selector is what in the js source. For example, these three declarations:

```
var slider = $('<div/>').addClass('jscarousal');
var leftbutton = $('<div/>').addClass('jscarousal-left');
var rightbutton = $('<div/>').addClass('jscarousal-right');
```

I can't tell which divs in the html are being affected, so that I can change the divs to a ul or li. If it were just these three lines, I'm sure 10 minutes of guessing would get me where I need to be, but there is more like 30 places in the js file.

I have a feeling this is basic js/jquery, so I googled it, but couldn't find something that translated or taught me what I needed to know. Any javascript experts out there have a free minute to show me how to figure out which divs need to be ul's and which need to be li's?

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help!

--Mark

Answer (score 1):

Inside jsCarousel.js (where the code starts on line 2), change the `div` to an `li` in these lines: `22, 43, 44`

Change line 74 to this:  `$('> div > li', slidercontents).css('display', '');`

Inside jsCarousel.css, add `margin:0;` and `padding:0;` to `.jscarousel-contents`  (line 35)

also change `.jscarousal-contents > div > div`  to `.jscarousal-contents > div > li`

That should do it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the js is like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#jsCarousel').jsCarousel({ onthumbnailclick: function(src) { alert(src); }, autoscroll: true });
});
```

And the structure of html is like this

```
<div id="jsCarousel">
            <div>
                <img src="images/img_1.jpg"><br>
                <span class="thumbnail-text">Image Text</span></div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/img_2.jpg"><br>
                <span class="thumbnail-text">Image Text</span></div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/img_3.jpg"><br>
                <span class="thumbnail-text">Image Text</span></div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/img_4.jpg"><br>
                <span class="thumbnail-text">Image Text</span></div>
            .........
            .........

        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks experimentX, but I'm not having trouble locating the script. I need help with changing the script to fit a different html structure, with the purpose of as little "wheel reinvention" as possible...

Comment: @Mark i guess i can't help you with this.